# Repeating items in the list

Tags: c#, list, repeat, items

Items that has the same item numbers should not repeat in the list, I tried this piece of code but it's not helping.

```
if (salesX.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SalesList saleX in salesX.ToList())
    {
        int index = sales.FindIndex(item => item.ItemNumber == saleX.ItemNumber);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            sales[index].PosQuantity = +saleX.PosQuantity;
            sales[index].PosSales = +saleX.PosSales;

        }
        else { sales.Add(saleX); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a matching item at the beginning of the list, you will still add a duplicate.
You want to check whether index is zero as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping. If you have a time can you please help me out at this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168572/what-is-the-optimum-way-of-getting-records-from-database-in-scenario-that-you-ha

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create a Dictionary list to define if the item exist.

The Dictionary would list all the unique ItemNumbers and you would use the ContainsKey method to determine if it already exists.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to `index != -1` , and it should work

```
if (index != -1)
{
    sales[index].PosQuantity = +saleX.PosQuantity;
    sales[index].PosSales = +saleX.PosSales;

}
```